# .htaccess file keeps having Internal Errors 500 and 403

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I don't know why, but on my host for my website my .htaccess continues to throw apache errors (500 and 403).

My .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php/?node=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php/?node=$1 [L,QSA]
```

which part of this could be causing this? I'm not very familiar with htaccess so I wouldn't begin to know.

Comment: What URL's are throwing what errors?

Comment: Are you sure the .htaccess is throwing the errors? If some scripts work and others don't, it's probably the scripts rather than the .htaccess throwing the errors.

Comment: Just going to the domain name at all, www.example.com

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure that is is .htaccess, I have been using this same htaccess file for a few weeks, and only recently has it been giving me a problem, at first I thought it was just my webserver host (because it's a pretty crappy one), but after doing some Googleing I saw that .htaccess could cause these errors, so I'm not sure. I'm leaning back to it being something to do with the server, or something else.